# how to check if a folder or directory is exist on a remote path in php

Tags: php, ftp

I am new to PHP, FTP connection.
I have to check a folder on a remote location ( ftp location ) that whether this folder exist or not.
I have tried through curl but it is not showing correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it would be easier to use an FTP PHP library , try this one [php-ftp-library](https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client)

Comment: bro,
thanks for your time and quick response. I will use it in some other project.
we donot want to add new library.
any other answer.
thanks in advanced

Comment: @AngularDeveloper You can use regular FTP conn and then do a whatever you want. List files and folders, send files or even download files. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php

Comment: @marcogmonteiro you may also try this library https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-client, if you work in a big project.

Answer (score -1):

try to use this code:

```
    <?php
    $path = 'your file name';
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: bro, Its remote file so as per my knowledge , we cannot check with is_dir.